# discord.py bot "The check functions for command failed"

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a discord bot and every time I try and run a command from a cog if gives me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\addis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\addis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\addis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 778, in prepare
    raise CheckFailure('The check functions for command {0.qualified_name} failed.'.format(self))
discord.ext.commands.errors.CheckFailure: The check functions for command avatar failed.
```

and this is my code

```py
import os
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix="!",  # Change to desired prefix
    case_insensitive=True  # Commands aren't case-sensitive
)

bot.author_id = DISCORD ID

@bot.event 
async def on_ready():  # When the bot is ready
    print("I'm in")
    print(bot.user)  # Prints the bot's username and identifier



extensions = [
    'cogs.cog_example', 'cogs.cog_start'  # Same name as it would be if you were importing it
]

if __name__ == '__main__':  # Ensures this is the file being ran
    for extension in extensions:
        bot.load_extension(extension)  # Loades every extension.

token = "TOKEN" 
bot.run(token)  # Starts the bot
```

and this is the cog that was having the problem

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class start(commands.Cog, name='start Commands'):
    '''These are the start commands'''

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    async def cog_check(self, ctx):  
        '''
        The default check for this cog whenever a command is used. Returns True if the command is allowed.
        '''
        return ctx.author.id == self.bot.author_id

    @commands.command(name="avatar", aliases=['av']) 
    async def avatar(self, ctx):
        print("bruh")


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(start(bot))
```

I was wondering what coursed this and how i could fix it (I was using a template)

Comment: If the `cog_check` function returns `False` that error is raised... Have you coded it yourself?

Comment: I am using a template but that function is in the other cog and that one works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you added a name to

`class start(commands.Cog, name='start Commands'):`

You have to add it to the setup function:

```
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(start(bot), name='start Commands')
```